# Can J2V8 execute anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, j2v8

I'm trying to execute this piece of javascript code

```
(function() {
    var z = '';
    var b = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i += 2) {
        z = z + parseInt(b.substring(i, i + 2), 16) + ',';
    }
    z = z.substring(0, z.length - 1);
    eval(eval('String.fromCharCode(' + z + ')'));
})();
```

but I got this error:

```
undefined:1: ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

If I assign the function to a variable, I haven't neither error nor result.

```
var a = function() {
    var z = '';
    var b = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i += 2) {
        z = z + parseInt(b.substring(i, i + 2), 16) + ',';
    }
    z = z.substring(0, z.length - 1);
    eval(eval('String.fromCharCode(' + z + ')'));
};
```

Have you got any idea on how run this script with J2V8?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN)` - WTF? Please post your actual value of `b` that you get the error for.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I don't know what the JS is supposed to do. You have an `eval` wrapped in an `eval`, and the function has no return statement. Plus, `xxxxx` doesn't appear to be a valid input.

Having said all that, if I remove the wrapped eval, use a number for the the variable `b` and return the result, it works fine for me.

`@Test
    public void testExample2() {
        String jsCode = "(function() {\n"
                + "var z = '';\n"
                + "var b = '12345678';\n"
                + "for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i += 2) {\n"
                + "    z = z + parseInt(b.substring(i, i + 2), 16) + ',';\n"
                + "}\n"
                + "z = z.substring(0, z.length - 1);\n"
                + "return eval('String.fromCharCode(' + z + ')');\n"
                + "})();";
        Object result = v8.executeScript(jsCode);
        System.out.println(result);
    }`